# Is "hineintun" a commonly used verb?

Tags: verb, usage

I was wondering if this word is in common usage. I've tried creating English sentences that would translate using it, but the translator always comes back with "stecken", "legen", or some other verb. The only example sentences using it that I could find where either from scientific/academic sources, or the bible. In what contexts would it be more appropriate to use as compared to other verbs with a similar meaning?

Comment: DWDS is a good place to find out how often a word is used; it gives *hineintun* a rating of 2 out of 7. DWDS also gives examples where the word is used in newpapers etc. I think generally machine translators will be biased in favor of using more common words. In the example I tried, going German->English->German, the translator substituted *einbringen*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a normal German word, composed from the common prefix *hinein* (this describes a movement into something, seen from a point of view that is outside the target container) and the verb *tun* (to do, to perform) which also is very common.

The combined verb *hineintun* itself is not used very often, but it still is a valid and correct German word, that every native speaker will understand.

It's meaning can be derived from its two components: Literally it means *"to do/perform something into something else".* But a better translation of coarse is *"to put something into something else".* (Also "to put" is one of the many translations of "tun".)

But for moving things into something there are many other verbs, that describe the kind of movement more accurate than *tun,* and you also can combine all of them with the prefix *hinein.* And because they all provide more information about the movement, they are all used more frequently:

- geben = to give, to put

  > etwas in etwas anderes **hineingeben**
  > **to put** something **inside** something else
- stecken = to stick

  > etwas in etwas anderes **hineinstecken**
  > **to stick** something **inside** something else
- werfen = to throw

  > etwas in etwas anderes **hineinwerfen**
  > **to throw** something **inside** something else
- stellen = to put, so that it then stands upright

  > etwas in etwas anderes **hineinstellen**
  > **to put** something **inside** something else so that is then stands upright
- legen = to put, so that it then lays flat

  > etwas in etwas anderes **hineinlegen**
  > **to put** something **inside** something else so that is then lays flat
- and many more

And because all these verbs provides more information that *tun* or *hineintun,* it is good style to prefer them over *tun/hineintun.*

---

Note, that all verbs that start with the prefix *hinein-* are separable verbs:

> Futur I: Ich werde das Hemd in den Koffer **hineinlegen.**
> I will put my shirt into the suitcase.
>
> Präsens: Ich **lege** das Hemd in den Koffer **hinein.**
> I will put my shirt into the suitcase.

And very often you also can read from the context, that the movement has a target inside something, and that the speaker is outside this container. So very often the prefix *"hinein-"* doesn't provide any additional information ant therefore can be omitted:

> Ich werde das Hemd in den Koffer **legen.**
> Ich **lege** das Hemd in den Koffer.

This it true for *hineintun* too. The following sentences all have the same meaning (disregarding that *legen* and *stecken* carry more information than *tun*):

> Ich werde das Hemd in den Koffer **hineintun.**
> Ich werde das Hemd in den Koffer **hineinlegen.**
> Ich werde das Hemd in den Koffer **tun.**
> Ich werde das Hemd in den Koffer **legen.**
> I will **put** the shirt into the suitcase.

Also:

> Ich werde den Steckling in the Erde **hineintun.**
> Ich werde den Steckling in the Erde **hineinstecken.**
> Ich werde den Steckling in the Erde **tun.**
> Ich werde den Steckling in the Erde **stecken.**
> I will stick the seedling into the earth.

So, it is ok, that a back-translation of *hineintun* returns *legen* or *stecken* or any other verb of movement.

Comment: "The combined verb hineintun itself is not used very often, but it still is a valid and correct German word, that every native speaker will understand." Germans (German speakers?) are taught at school, not to use *tun* as an auxiliary verb. It's probably a kind of hypercorrection, but use of the verb *tun* is often considered bad style.

Comment: @Roland: It is not use *tun* as an auxiliary verb in my examples: Usage as auxiliary verb: *»Erich tut den Deckel auf den Topf geben.«* This is not standard German. You can find it in colloquial speech, but in standard German this is wrong. Compare to the usage as full verb: *»Erich tut den Deckel auf den Topf.«* This is correct standard German, but bad style, because you could use a more accurate verb like *»Erich gibt den Deckel auf den Topf.«* But there are sentences, where it is ok to use *tun,* like in this example *»Ilse tut nichts den ganzen Tag.«* or *»Was tust du hier?«*

Comment: Umm, I haven't claimed that it is used as an auxiliary verb in your examples. Also, »Erich gibt den Deckel auf den Topf.« is Austrian/Southern German.

Comment: @Roland Really? I'm Austrian, so this didn't occur to me. What would you say instead in non-colloquial style? _Setzt_?

Comment: @phipsgabler Ich lege den Deckel auf den Topf.

Comment: @phipsgabler *Erich setzt den Deckel auf den Topf* appeals to me, but I would expect this rather in literature than in everyday life (in Germany). In the latter, I mostly hear, e.g.: *Erich, kannst du mal bitte den Deckel auf den Topf machen?* I've never come across *legen* though.

Comment: Fascinating! We should create some kind of map of regional put-verbs :) I might do some research on that.

Comment: @phipsgabler: Dann könntest du auch gleich untersuchen, wo man Hüte, Krawatten, Ketten, Schals, Uhren, Gürtel usw. anzieht, und wo man sie aufsetzt, anlegt, umbindet usw.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Der [Atlas zur deutschen Alltagssprache](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/thematisches-register/#_Toc42783757) hat schon mal zu beidem nichts wirklich Brauchbares. Die Brille aufsetzen/anziehen/anlegen geht vielleicht am ehesten in Richtung deiner Frage.

Answer (score 1):

As already answered, *hineintun* is perfectly legal.

I strongly assume, that the reason for the rare occurrence is, that there is a shorter variant, saving a whole syllable:

> [Duden: reintun](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/reintun)

It would have considered it as colloquial, but Duden does not confirm this.

It could be used as in

> Hast du schon Salz ins Nudelwasser reingetan?

Comment: If a directional preposition such as *ins Nudelwasser* is present, I personally would just use *tun*. Conversely, I would use *reintun* when it is absent: *Hast du schon Salz reingetan?*

Comment: I think "reintun" is in the example of "Nudelwasser" a slangy word, because using of "hinein" or "(he)rein" depends on the direction, the relation from the speaker to the pot. If the direction is from the speaker into the pot --> "hinein". If the speaker sits in a big pot, so the salt comes to him, then --> "herein". But in colloquial language German speakers makes usually no difference between "herein" and "hinein".